# Is there a significance of the term "Ribbon Girls"?

Tags: keijo

In the East-West War arc, Nozomi and the chi-kung split personality girl are referred to as "Ribbon Girls".

Does this have any correlation to their ranking in training? Or is it just because they both happened to be wearing ribbons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's just that they both happen to wear ribbons. There isn't said anything about their ranking in training and ribbons.

Comment: Yeah I kinda thought so, but at the same time I felt like it may have been a detail that I overlooked somehow. Thanks for replying